# How to increase the height of the Flickity slider?

Tags: html, css, flickity

I am using [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/v1/). I have groupCell true. Now the issue is, I am not able to increase the height of the image or slider height.
Also, I have to display the 1 slider in mobile device.

Would you help me out?

```js
$('.slideset').flickity({
  // options
  cellAlign: 'left',
  wrapAround: true,
  contain: true,
  //groupCells:'%',
  groupCells: true,
  prevNextButtons: true
});
```

```css
.carousel-cell {
  width: calc( ( 100% - 10px) / 3);
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f00;
  counter-increment: carousel-cell;
}

.slidesetImg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  padding: 5px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
@media ( min-width: 768px ) {
  .carousel-cell {
/* 1 cells in group */
width: calc( ( 100% - 20px ) / 1);
  } 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="main-carousel slideset">
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <div class="slidesetImg"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <div class="slidesetImg"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <div class="slidesetImg"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <div class="slidesetImg"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <div class="slidesetImg"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <div class="slidesetImg"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <div class="slidesetImg"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <div class="slidesetImg"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Flickity has the option `setGallerySize` which sets the height of the carousel to the height of the tallest cell. It enables by default.

Use `setGallerySize: false` if you prefer to size the carousel with CSS, rather than using the size of cells.

```
$('.slideset').flickity({
  // options
  setGallerySize: false
  cellAlign: 'left',
  wrapAround: true,
  contain: true,
  //groupCells:'%',
  groupCells: true,
  prevNextButtons: true
});

    /* carousel height */
    .carousel-cell {
      height: SOME HEIGHT;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... but   setGallerySize: false not working. I am not getting the my slider.

Comment: I am not getting my images, I am getting only arrow. Can you share the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```
.slidesetImg{
height:100% !important;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh yes, I  tried the same but it was not working. Now it's working. What about responsive?

Comment: you want just one slider in mobile device? add display:none  in mobile media query for other sliders

Comment: I want only one slider in mobile device

Comment: add a class to all other sliders and make it display:none in @media